# Android FFmpeg grab frames in parallel from a video

Tags: android, ffmpeg, javacv

Is there any way to read frames from an mp4 video using **JavaCV** in parallel?
I know that we could grab frames using `FFmpegFrameGrabber` but is there any other efficient method like using `FrameGrabber.Array` ?, I tried the below code but its not working.

```
frames = new Frame[grabber.getLengthInFrames()];
                frameGrabbers = new FFmpegFrameGrabber[grabber.getLengthInFrames()];
                *//*for (FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber : frameGrabbers) {
                    grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(path);
                }*//*
                for (int i = 0; i < grabber.getLengthInFrames(); i++) {
                    frameGrabbers[i] = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(path);
                }
                grabberArray = grabber.createArray(frameGrabbers);

                grabberArray.start();

                frames = grabberArray.grab();
                grabberArray.release();
```

The app crashes when I call `grabberArray.start()`.
Thanks.

Comment: What kind of a crash is it? What error message?

Comment: I don't remember now, I should have posted the crash log as well.